# Blazor renders components but immediately fails to connect

Tags: blazor

I've followed [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/integrate-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1) (and a number of blogs) for adding blazor components to a razor pages app. The razor page is rendering the components perfectly, but then immediately get 'trying to reconnect' which always fails. Console output says (running on localhost, obviously):

```
[2020-07-20T00:22:59.957Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://localhost:44306/_blazor'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-07-20T00:22:59.961Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection.
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-07-20T00:22:59.969Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Binary'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-07-20T00:22:59.970Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: https://localhost:44306/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1.
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-07-20T00:23:00.145Z] Debug: Selecting transport 'WebSockets'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-07-20T00:23:00.174Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:44306/_blazor?id=vuY411dkAsPan4fQrNN3aw.
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-07-20T00:23:00.175Z] Debug: The HttpConnection connected successfully.
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-07-20T00:23:00.175Z] Debug: Sending handshake request.
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-07-20T00:23:00.176Z] Information: Using HubProtocol 'blazorpack'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-07-20T00:23:00.182Z] Debug: Server handshake complete.
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-07-20T00:23:00.182Z] Debug: HubConnection connected successfully.
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-07-20T00:23:00.327Z] Information: Close message received from server.
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-07-20T00:23:00.329Z] Debug: HttpConnection.stopConnection(undefined) called while in state Disconnecting.
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-07-20T00:23:00.332Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.'.
e.log @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stopConnection @ blazor.server.js:1
transport.onclose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.close @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stop @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
a @ blazor.server.js:1
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
M @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stopInternal @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
M @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stop @ blazor.server.js:1
e.processIncomingData @ blazor.server.js:1
connection.onreceive @ blazor.server.js:1
i.onmessage @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-07-20T00:23:00.333Z] Debug: HubConnection.connectionClosed(Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.) called while in state Connected.
blazor.server.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.
    at e.processIncomingData (blazor.server.js:1)
    at e.connection.onreceive (blazor.server.js:1)
    at WebSocket.i.onmessage (blazor.server.js:1)
e.processIncomingData @ blazor.server.js:1
connection.onreceive @ blazor.server.js:1
i.onmessage @ blazor.server.js:1
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:8
a @ blazor.server.js:8
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
r @ blazor.server.js:8
E @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ Eol:12448
blazor.server.js:19 [2020-07-20T00:23:03.338Z] Error: TypeError: window.Blazor.reconnect is not a function
e.log @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
r @ blazor.server.js:19
e.attemptPeriodicReconnection @ blazor.server.js:19
e @ blazor.server.js:19
e.onConnectionDown @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
e.completeClose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.connectionClosed @ blazor.server.js:1
connection.onclose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stopConnection @ blazor.server.js:1
transport.onclose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.close @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stop @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
a @ blazor.server.js:1
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
M @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stopInternal @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
M @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stop @ blazor.server.js:1
e.processIncomingData @ blazor.server.js:1
connection.onreceive @ blazor.server.js:1
i.onmessage @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:19 [2020-07-20T00:23:06.346Z] Error: TypeError: window.Blazor.reconnect is not a function
e.log @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
r @ blazor.server.js:19
e.attemptPeriodicReconnection @ blazor.server.js:19
e @ blazor.server.js:19
e.onConnectionDown @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
e.completeClose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.connectionClosed @ blazor.server.js:1
connection.onclose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stopConnection @ blazor.server.js:1
transport.onclose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.close @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stop @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
a @ blazor.server.js:1
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
M @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stopInternal @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
M @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stop @ blazor.server.js:1
e.processIncomingData @ blazor.server.js:1
connection.onreceive @ blazor.server.js:1
i.onmessage @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:19 [2020-07-20T00:23:09.353Z] Error: TypeError: window.Blazor.reconnect is not a function
e.log @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
r @ blazor.server.js:19
e.attemptPeriodicReconnection @ blazor.server.js:19
e @ blazor.server.js:19
e.onConnectionDown @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
e.completeClose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.connectionClosed @ blazor.server.js:1
connection.onclose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stopConnection @ blazor.server.js:1
transport.onclose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.close @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stop @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
a @ blazor.server.js:1
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
M @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stopInternal @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
M @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stop @ blazor.server.js:1
e.processIncomingData @ blazor.server.js:1
connection.onreceive @ blazor.server.js:1
i.onmessage @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:19 [2020-07-20T00:23:12.375Z] Error: TypeError: window.Blazor.reconnect is not a function
e.log @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
r @ blazor.server.js:19
e.attemptPeriodicReconnection @ blazor.server.js:19
e @ blazor.server.js:19
e.onConnectionDown @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
e.completeClose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.connectionClosed @ blazor.server.js:1
connection.onclose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stopConnection @ blazor.server.js:1
transport.onclose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.close @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stop @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
a @ blazor.server.js:1
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
M @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stopInternal @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
M @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stop @ blazor.server.js:1
e.processIncomingData @ blazor.server.js:1
connection.onreceive @ blazor.server.js:1
i.onmessage @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:19 [2020-07-20T00:23:15.390Z] Error: TypeError: window.Blazor.reconnect is not a function
e.log @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
a @ blazor.server.js:19
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:19
r @ blazor.server.js:19
e.attemptPeriodicReconnection @ blazor.server.js:19
e @ blazor.server.js:19
e.onConnectionDown @ blazor.server.js:19
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
e.completeClose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.connectionClosed @ blazor.server.js:1
connection.onclose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stopConnection @ blazor.server.js:1
transport.onclose @ blazor.server.js:1
e.close @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stop @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
a @ blazor.server.js:1
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
M @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stopInternal @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
M @ blazor.server.js:1
e.stop @ blazor.server.js:1
e.processIncomingData @ blazor.server.js:1
connection.onreceive @ blazor.server.js:1
i.onmessage @ blazor.server.js:1
```

- _Layout.cshtml contains `<base href="/">` in head and at the end of `<body>` it has:

  ```html
  <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
  <script>
      Blazor.start({
          configureSignalR: function (builder) {
              builder.configureLogging(1); // LogLevel.Information
          }
      });
  </script>
  ```
- I have _Imports.razor at the root *and* in the Pages folder, containing

  ```
  @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
  @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
  @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
  @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
  @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
  @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
  @using Microsoft.JSInterop
  @using MyAppNamespace
  ```
- Startup.cs has `services.AddServerSideBlazor();` in `ConfigureServices`, and Configure says:

  ```cs
  .MapRazorPages();
  .MapBlazorHub();
  .MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
  ```
- _Host.cshtml is in the Pages folder, containing

  ```
  @page "/blazor"
  @{
      Layout = "_Layout";
  }

  <app>
      <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
  </app>
  ```

Based on the console logs, connecting from the Index page works fine, but not for another page that uses components.

I am obviously missing some bit of plumbing, but I don't know what it is. What am I missing?

---

Update: I tried using a blazor component in the Index page, where it seemed client was connecting ok, but I see the same thing: The page renders the components, and then the connection is closed and no attempt to reconnect succeeds.

Comment: I have this problem. aspnet core 3.1

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

I observed this behavior when passing a complex object as a parameter to my component.

```
<component type="typeof(MyComponent)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-Data="@myComplexObject" />
```

It seems that the component tag helper only works with simple type paremeters.

For me, I was able to work around this by setting the render-mode to `Static`, but this won't be a good solution for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You said: _Layout.cshtml contains `<href="/">`

If this isn't a typo, change it to `<base href="/">`

Comment: Thanks for noticing the typo in my post! The code actually has: `<base href="/">`

Comment: So, to be clear, that isn't the issue. Why is the connection being closed?